# Is "Job pool" term is equivelent to Virtual memory space?

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory

According to Operating System textbook: (Galvin et al.) the definition of Job pool is;

> Main Memory is too small to accommodate all jobs, hence, the jobs are kept initially on the disk in the job pool.

I was wondering if I can use the term job pool and virtual memory space interchangeably?

Comment: feel free for any queries.

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about batch scheduling here.

Answer (score 1):

**NO, not at all**. Virtual memory represents the program's address space, that is it represents the addresses generated by the **CPU**. Its basically there, so that we don't have to bother about actual physical addresses(main memory addresses) while writing programs. It is the duty of the translation mechanism(`paging`) that will convert these virtual addresses to real physical addresses.

Whereas, **job pool**, is the pool from which **long term scheduler** will pick the jobs to be converted to programs by loading them into main memory. It has nothing to do with the virtual memory.